# How do you store a user input into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How does one store user input from an `<input type="text">` into an array in Javascript?
I have this so far:

```
<input type="text" id="user_input">
<button type="button>click</button>

<script>
const myArray = [];
//what next? I don't mind using console.log to test
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you can use the [onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) attribute within the `<button>`, which can execute a function when the button is clicked.

```
<button type="button" onclick="addData()">click</button>
```

On your JavaScript, you will define the addData() function.

```
const inputData = [];

const addData = () => {
  const inputText = document.getElementById('user_input');
  inputData.push(inputText.value);
}
```

Here is a demo for you:

```html
<input type="text" id="user_input">
<button type="button" onclick="addData()">click</button>

<script>
const inputData = [];

const addData = () => {
  const inputText = document.getElementById('user_input');
  inputData.push(inputText.value);
  console.log(inputData);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is regarding adding input into the array when the user clicks the button, then this would suffice:

```html
<input type="text" id="user_input">
<button type="button" onclick="storeInput()">store input</button>

<script>
const storedUserInputs = [];
function storeInput() {
  var input = document.getElementById("user_input"); // get reference to the input element
  storedUserInputs.push(input.value); // catpure the value
  input.value = ""; //reset the input value
  console.log(storedUserInputs);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

a spaghetti solution might be as below snippet,

```js
values = [];

function addRecord() {
  var inp = document.getElementById('inputtext');
  values.push(inp.value);
  inp.value = "";  
}

function displayRecord() {
  document.getElementById("values").innerHTML = values.join(", ");
}
```

```html
 <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter the Input</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="inputtext" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><button type="button" id="add" onclick="addRecord();">Add </button>
                <button type="button" id="display" onclick="displayRecord();">Display</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>

   <div id='values'>
</div>
```